# How to use RView tool in Bot Builder (C# SDK) to localize strings in Form Flow

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I need to localize all the strings and Enums in FormFlow for the German language. How can I use RView tool to generate resource files? I have read following but I couldn't understand how to use it. Can someone explain in simple steps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-localize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it's pretty clear, but let's try to write some steps:

1. In your code, look for the static method that builds the form, for
   example [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/Models/Order.cs#L68) in the [ContosoFlowers](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers) example.
2. Once you found it, then capture two things: the namespace and the assembly name. In the context of the [ContosoFlowers](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers) sample the namespace it will be `ContosoFlowers.Models` and the assembly `ContosoFlowers.dll` (it's on the bin folder after you build the project).
3. Run the `rview` tool as `rview -g {AssemblyName} {Namespace}.{NameOfTheBuildFormMethod}.` Following the [ContosoFlowers](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers) sample it will be `rview -g ContosoFlowers.dll ContosoFlowers.Models.BuildOrderForm`
4. Folllow the steps described in the *Configure your project* section of the doumentation to add the resulting `resx` file to your solution.

> *Note*: The RView tool is included with the BotBuilder SDK nuget package. Once you add the NuGet to your project if you go to packages folder and then to the Microsoft.Bot.Builder folder, you will find a tools folder with the `RView.exe` file. Alternatively, you can get the source code of the tool at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Tools/RView
>
> *Note 2*: If you make changes and want to recreate the resx file, do not forget to change the Neutral Language (back) to '(None)', or else the rview tool will give you an error message (Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Missing resources System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ...)

Comment: Jadlib , I had put that in command window of VS2015 and it say "Command "rview" is not valid."

Comment: But... do you have the rview tool in that path??  Look for the tool in the packages folder of your project inside the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.X.X.X.X (where X is the version) folder

Comment: @Jadlib, Is RView tool available as nuget package? I tried to look for that name and I couldn't find it

Comment: No, is coming as part of the Microsoft.Bot.Builder nuget package, which you  are already using in your project. Go to the packages folder and the look for the folder that starts with Microsoft.Bot.Buider

Comment: Alternatively, you can get the source code of the tool at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Tools/RView

Comment: This may be a stupid question, since i am new to Visual Studio. Do I need to add that RView.exe file as reference? Microsoft.Bot.Builder is already added as a reference. How can i run that file?

Comment: Is an exe file. You should run it on a CMD/console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154438/discussion-between-ehsan-ul-haq-and-ezequiel-jadib).

Comment: I don't agree with your note 2. I would rather say: if when running the botbuilder, you get the "Missing resources" exception, then 1. delete the resx corresponding to the form and corresponding to the neutral culture (don't delete the other resx corresponding to other cultures), 2. rebuild your assembly, 3. use the Rview tool to regenerate this resx file 4. replace this new neutral resx file, and 5. complete the missing resources to other localized resx files. (bottom line: localization in botbuilder *sucks big time*)